# How to get database in php using class & function oops concepts

Tags: php, oop

I am new developer in php. I'm writing below code a class and functions to connect to the database. but code was not working how to create class and function oops concept help me.

**code:**

```
class database {

#code
var $host = "localhost";
var $username ="root";
var $password ="";

var $dbase ="blue";
var $myconnect;

function connectTodata()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);

    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Cannot Connect to the datagase");
    }
    else
    {
        $his->myconnect = $conn;
        echo "Connect Established";
    }
    return $myconnect;

}
 function selectDatabase() // selecting the database.
{
    mysql_select_db($this->database);  //use php inbuild functions for select database

    if(mysql_error()) // if error occured display the error message
    {

        echo "Cannot find the database ".$this->database;

    }
     echo "Database selected..";       
}

function closeConnection() // close the connection
{
    mysql_close($this->myconn);

    echo "Connection closed";
   }
}
```

Comment: `$his->myconnect` missing a `t` and you're also calling `$this->myconn` where you're doing `myconnect`

Comment: your code is totally broken. `$his->myconnect`? Maybe `$this->myconnect` ? Then again, just `return $myconnect;`? Just read it patiently and you'll see things like this

Comment: (1) your class is using [`php4 oop style`](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.php) and you really should be updating to [`php5 oop style`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and (2) you really should stop using `mysql` and use `mysli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it work:

```
class database 
{
    #code
    var $host = "localhost";
    var $username ="root";
    var $password ="";

    var $dbase ="blue";
    var $myconnect;

    function connectTodata()
    {
        $this->myconnect = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        if(!$this->myconnect) die("Cannot Connect to the datagase");
        echo "Connect Established";
        return $this->myconnect;
    }

    function selectDatabase() // selecting the database.
    {
        mysql_select_db($this->database);  //use php inbuild functions for select database

        if(mysql_error()) // if error occured display the error message
        {
            echo "Cannot find the database ".$this->database;
        }
     echo "Database selected..";       
    }

    function closeConnection() // close the connection
    {
        mysql_close($this->myconnect);
        echo "Connection closed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the errors as described by the previous posters, then try this to start:

```
$database_connection=new database();
$database_handle=$database_connection->connectTodata();
$database_connection->selectDatabase();

$database_connection->closeConnection();
unset($database_connection);
exit();
```

and in the space between the chunks of code, you can add your mysql queries and use $database_handle as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use constructor so that you don't need to call class function everytime  :

```
 class database {
    var $host = "localhost";
    var $username ="root";
    var $password ="";

    var $dbase ="blue";
    var $myconnect;

    function __construct()  {
        $this->myconnect = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);

       if( !$this->myconnect )  {
            $msg  = "could not connect to mysql database <Br/>";
            $msg .= mysql_error();
            die($msg);
        }

        $db_connect = mysql_select_db($this->dbase, $this->myconnect);

        if( !$db_connect )  {
            die(" can not select database \n".mysql_error());
        }
    }

    function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->myconnect);
    }
}

// call database 
$con = new database();
```

Comment: This does work, however it wouldn't take much to be as `mysqli_` ;-) If the OP is on PHP 5.5, it will throw back a deprecation warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of Defining them something like

```
define("DB_SERVER_NAME","your host");
define("DB_USER_NAME","your user name");
define("DB_USER_PASSWORD","your password");
define("DB_DATABASE_NAME","your database");
```

now the connection file:

```
class DBClass{
public $DB_LINK;
public $DB_DATABASE_NAME;
function DBClass($Main_DB = FALSE){
$this->DB_LINK = @mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER_NAME,DB_USER_NAME,DB_USER_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE_NAME);
if(! $this->DB_LINK){
die("<h2>Could not connect to Database.</h2>");
}
}
function __destruct(){
mysqli_close($this->DB_LINK);
}   
}
```

This works perfectly for me